# Drag elements to specific position using jquery or simple js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**First of all I am afraid for asking this question because you can rate me bad but I have to ask.
I will delete the question by myself just let me know in comments.**

I want to move the elements to specific position when user move the an element to right 25px then it should automatically move to the right element like new ul > li should be created in its a first 2nd level of element then if someone drag this element which has moved more to the 25px right then it should also move to the right and it should be the 3rd level and so on. and also to the left side drag to revert to the orignal position
I want to make a tree structure like this when someone drag the element to the right or left then

```
[----1--1st level--]
[----2--1st level--]
  [----1--2nd level--]
    [----1--3rd level--]
    [----2--3rd level--]
      [----1--4th level--]
  [----2--2nd level--]
    [----1----]
    [----2----]
    [----3----]
```

how can I do that? is there any js library? Thanks

Comment: I created this idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825642/create-a-tree-with-dynamic-level-feature-for-its-nodes-movable-nodes-by-jquer) but it created by jQuery. you can think about it's codes and simulate it with mootools or change your js framework to jquery if it is possible for you...

Anyway if it's useful for you so please change your question title and its tags and include jQuery in them then i write this comment as and answer here. ok?

Comment: thats ok with me but I can't drag the nodes to right here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/RAM_Designer/vwnneLfr/4/

Comment: in this example you can use arrow keys of your keyboard after you click on one node. it is a safe way to do this. do you tested it by arrow keys?

Comment: I see but is there a way we can drag using mouse?

Comment: Sure, we can do this by jQuery, i can change my codes and create an answer here if you want, but here i cant' do it because your question title and its tags are about mootools else you change it and include jQuery in them.

Comment: I changed ram you can answer now.

Comment: Ok,I will write an answer after my works soon. i want merge the idea of [this codes](http://jsfiddle.net/Jge9z/) with [my code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RAM_Designer/vwnneLfr/4/)

Comment: i write a new answer and updated my project to a newer version that support keyboard and mouse together. now you can use it. just click on level part of each node and drag... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created & provided this idea **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825642/create-a-tree-with-dynamic-level-feature-for-its-nodes-movable-nodes-by-jquer/26825643#26825643)** on stackoverflow before.

I know it can be improved and make a better version of it but now you can use it and enjoy....

## It's features:

### »» Support keyboard arrow keys to move the nodes (Left & Right)

### »» Support dragging the nodes by Mouse to Right & Left

### »» Save level data of each node in DOM and show it on each node

**you can [test it on fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RAM_Designer/vwnneLfr/6/)**

---

**Result of my codes:**

[image]

**JS & jQuery**

```
/*Code by Ram >> https://stackoverflow.com/users/1474613/ram */

(function ($) {
    $.Noder = function (oneOfNodes) {
        this.element = '';
        oneOfNodes=(oneOfNodes instanceof $) ? oneOfNodes : $(oneOfNodes)
        this.baseX=oneOfNodes.position().left;
        this.currentX=0;
    };

    $.Noder.prototype = {
        InitEvents: function () {
            //`this` references the created instance object inside an instace's method,
            //however `this` is set to reference a DOM element inside jQuery event handler functions' scope.
            //So we take advantage of JS's lexical scope and assign the `this` reference to
            //another variable that we can access inside the jQuery handlers
            var that = this;
            //I'm using `document` instead of `this` so it will catch arrow keys
            //on the whole document and not just when the element is focused.
            //Also, Firefox doesn't fire the keypress event for non-printable characters
            //so we use a keydown handler
            $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                var key = e.which;
                if (key == 39) {
                    that.moveRight();
                } else if (key == 37) {
                    that.moveLeft();
                }
            });},
        setElement: function(element){
            this.element = (element instanceof $) ? element : $(element);
            console.log(this.element);
            this.currentX=this.element.position().left;
            console.log('currentX: '+this.currentX);
            this.element.addClass('active');
        },
        moveRight: function () {
            console.log('bseX: '+this.baseX);
            console.log('currentX: '+this.currentX);
            var max=(25*2)+this.baseX;
            console.log('max: '+max);
            if(this.currentX<max)
            {
                this.element.css("left", '+=' + 25);
                this.currentX=this.element.position().left;
                setElementLevel(this.element,this.currentX,this.baseX);
                console.log('currentX: '+this.currentX);
            }
        },
        moveLeft: function () {
            if(this.currentX>this.baseX)
            {
                this.element.css("left", '-=' + 25);
                this.currentX=this.element.position().left;
                setElementLevel(this.element,this.currentX,this.baseX);
                console.log('currentX: '+this.currentX);
            }
        }

    };
    $.Noder.defaultOptions = {
        currentX: 0
    };

}(jQuery));

function setElementLevel(element,currentX,baseX){
    var level=0;
    if (currentX==baseX+25)
        level=1;
    else if(currentX==baseX+25+25)
        level=2;
    element.data('level', level);
    setLevelOnElement(element);
}

function getElementLevel(element){
    console.log(element.data('level'));
    return element.data('level');
}

function setLevelOnElement(element){  
    var level = 0;
    if(typeof getElementLevel(element) !=='undefined')
        level = getElementLevel(element);
    console.log('my level: '+level);
    var $levelElement=element.find( ".node-level" );
    if ($levelElement && $levelElement.length>0)
    {
        $levelElement=$($levelElement[0]); 
        console.log($levelElement);
        $levelElement.html(level);
    }
}

var noder = new $.Noder($("#myTree>.node")[0]);

$("#myTree>.node").on('click',function(){
    $("#myTree>.node").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    });    
    console.log($(this)[0].id +' clicked')

    noder.setElement($(this)[0]);

})
noder.InitEvents();


$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dragging = null;
    var $myTree=$('ul#myTree');
    var $oneOfNodes=null;
    var baseX=0;
    if($myTree.length>0)
    {
        console.log($myTree);
        $oneOfNodes=$($myTree.children()[0]);
        console.log($oneOfNodes);
        baseX=$oneOfNodes.position().left;
        console.log('baseX >> '+baseX);
        console.log($myTree);
        var x=0;
        $('ul#myTree').find('li').each(function(){
            x++;
            console.log(x);
            setLevelOnElement($(this));
        });
    }

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if ($dragging) {
            var currentX=$dragging.position().left;
            if(e.pageX>(baseX+25) && e.pageX<(baseX+(2*25)))
            {
                $dragging.offset({left: (baseX+25)});
                setElementLevel($dragging,currentX,baseX);
            }
            else if((e.pageX)>(baseX+(2*25)) )
            {
                $dragging.offset({left: (baseX+(2*25))});
                setElementLevel($dragging,currentX,baseX);
            }
            else if(e.pageX<(baseX+25) )
            {
                $dragging.offset({left: (baseX)});
                setElementLevel($dragging,currentX,baseX);
            }
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on("mousedown",  function (e) {
        var $myTree=$('ul#myTree');
        if($(e.target) && $myTree && $myTree.length>0)
        {
            var $li=$(e.target).parent();
            var $ul=$(e.target).parent().parent();
            if ( $ul.is($myTree) && $(e.target).hasClass("node-level") )
            {
                $ul.find('li').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
                $li.addClass('active');
                $dragging = $($li);
            }
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        $dragging = null;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myTree">
    <li class="node" id="node1">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="node" id="node2">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="node" id="node3">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 3</span>
    </li>
    <li class="node" id="node4">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 4</span>
    </li>
    <li class="node" id="node5">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 5</span>
    </li>
    <li class="node" id="node6">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 6</span>
    </li>
    <li class="node" id="node7">
        <span class="node-level"></span>
        <span class="node-content">Node 7</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#myTree{
    margin:20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:11px;
}
#myTree>li>.node-level{
    padding:6px 10px;
    color:#ddd;
    background:gray;
    position:relative;
    cursor:move;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#myTree>li>.node-content{
    padding:5px; 15px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#myTree>.node:hover {
    background:#acd;
    color:#004;
}
#myTree>.node.active {
    border:1px #a66 solid;
    background:#fd8;
    color:#004;
}
#myTree>li.node {
    width:151px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin-top:2px;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0;
    color:#555;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
div { width:151px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin-top:2px;
    padding:5px 15px;
    color:#555;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc; }
```

Comment: This is probably better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Dave the question title changed by Mubasher and he said my answer is useful for him as an answer so i provide it again...

Comment: @emmanuel the question title changed by Mubasher and he said my answer is useful for him as an answer so i provide it again...

Comment: great I can customize your code to work with my framework thanks Ram

Comment: I'm happy that my codes could help you. if your question is a problem and you can not find it's answer so write it here. In stackoverflow sometimes some good question get down-vote or it's state take closed (!!!), i have some question in this case BUT i never afraid of some mistake managements or down-votes here when i know my question is a real problem then i write a new question here (every time i thought i should write...) So don't afraid to write your questions when your question is a real problem in your works. ;)

Comment: @RAM yeah thats fine the new edited version is a lot better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [html5sortable](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable) library to create a tree structure draggable list by using the `connectWith` option:

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
  handle: ".handle",
  connectWith: '.connected'
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Ubuntu, Sans-serif;
}
ul li {
  margin: 15px;
}
ul li .handle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5sortable/0.1.1/html.sortable.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable connected">
  <li><i class="fa fa-arrows handle"></i> First Level Foo</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-arrows handle"></i> First Level Bar</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sortable connected">
      <li><i class="fa fa-arrows handle"></i> Second Level</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The only downside is that it's a pretty clean library - it doesn't do a whole lot besides dragging, so everything else (dragging outside, creating new lists, etc.) you need to implement on your own (for example, in the snippet above if you drag all the items out of the inner list it "disappears" and you can't drag back to it).

But that being said, it shouldn't prove too difficult, as `html5sortable` has a neat little `reload` method so you can just call it every time you add a new `.sortable` element to the div:

```
$('.sortable').sortable('reload');
```

I just did something similar not long ago (I also used the [`finderSelect` plugi](http://evulse.github.io/finderSelect/)n with it to create a file-manager like behavior, although that might be overkill if you don't need all that).

Comment: I can't drag to right to create a 2nd and third level nodes?

Comment: @Mubasher no, as I said - it's not a "smart" library, it just makes it easier to create and manage draggable lists. From there you can make a manager that handles and creates new lists when this and that happens

Comment: @Mubasher Also, there's [this](http://boagworld.com/demos/sitemap/) along with a [tutorial](http://boagworld.com/dev/creating-a-draggable-sitemap-with-jquery/)

Comment: great tutorial although I will work on it after ram gives me the answer.